# Which console commands disable Steam achievements in Starfield?

Tags: steam, achievements, starfield

In the Steam edition of Starfield with achievements, the console can be activated with the <kbd>`</kbd> key. However, upon opening, I am warned:

> Use of certain console commands will disable achievements.

[image: Screenshot of warning regarding achievements being disabled by the use of console commands]

However, there's no list of offending commands, or "learn more" button to see *which* console commands will disable achievements and which ones are OK. I don't want to risk breaking achievements on my first playthrough, but I would like to experiment with some commands I've found, like speeding up how long it takes to rest in-game.

Which console commands disable achievements? Alternatively (if the list is much shorter), which ones do *not* disable them?

(I know there are Steam-compatible mods available to enable achievements while allowing console commands, but I'm not interested in that for the purposes of this question)

Comment: I wondered this the first time I accidentally hit the `~` button instead of `1`  but found that the internet was full of weird conflicting information, most of which ended up being "install this mod/modify this file and un-lock your save!"

Comment: I don't have a list, but I assume that all commands that give you some kind of advantage (more money, more health, more power, better weapons...) could disable the achievements. Commands to just change the color of your hair or weapon should not disable achievements. It would be useful to see such a list.